# How can you bulk add emails to publication lists?

Tags: email

I have a db of emails that receive all the campaigns we send. I have created 3 publication lists so that people can choose what campaigns they get. But how do I start this? I presume I need to add all the emails to my 3 publication lists and people can then choose. How can you bulk add emails to publication lists?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tested, it looks as though I should just import all my new customers into SFMC and use separate daily Import functions to import the customers into my publication lists. But I need to make sure I only "add only" customers rather than "Add and update" as that would continually overwrite the customer's publication edits.